# Error while trying to create android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i´m currently trying to create an android emulator using the AVD manager. 
When i put all the characteristics related to the emulator than click on create button i have this error :

Result of creating ADV device 
  /home/user/.android/avd/casca.ini (permission denied)

my path for creating the AVD is : /home/user/.android/avd/ so i dont have a path problem

i tried to change the permission to the avd folder using chmod a+x but i still have the same issue.

Can someone help me with this please
Thanks !

Comment: Create ur emulator by opening Android Studio in Run as Administrator.

Comment: actually i am doing this with ubuntu command line as root so normally i have all the permissions

Answer (score 0):

try with this: sudo -s chmod -R 777 /home/user/.android/